Access Excel logged In user token in my C# VSTO application
I have a C# desktop Application which uses the VSTO plug-in to work with Excel. I want to access the already logged-in user token in my application. Is there any way to get it? I have read about the MSAL.NET library but it says to register our app with the Azure admin account. Please suggest if we have any other way to access the Token.
Thanks in advance!
